# Javascript add transform as an inline style

Tags: javascript, css-transforms

I have a quick question: how can you add transforms as an inline style via JavaScript? For the last hour, I've been trying to solve this problem and also have been searching everywhere, but nothing worked. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
 <ul id="slider">
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
 </ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var windowWidth = $(window).width();
 var centerDistance = windowWidth / 2;
 var targets = $(".slide");
 var inlineTransform = '"' + "translateZ(" + centerDistance + "px)" + '"';
 for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
     targets[i].style.WebkitTransform = inlineTransform;
     targets[i].style.msTransform = inlineTransform;
     targets[i].style.transform = inlineTransform;
 }
```

According to w3schools, nothing is spelled wrong and all the prefixes are correct: [w3schools DOM style transform](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp)

The syntax should be correct too. I don't get any error messages and this code works if I use other styles.

Comment: You're adding quotes to the outside of your string. You don't need those.

Comment: "According to w3schools..." No! Bad! W3Schools is not an authoritative source of documentation, and has no affiliation with [W3C](https://www.w3.org/), which is _completely_ different. W3Schools has a [history of inaccurate and poor documentation](http://www.w3fools.com/), as well as deceptive branding, and should not be trusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add additional quotes to that string. A string is a string. Quotes are only needed for string literals inside code, and you already have those.

Here's a jQuery version:

```
var centerDistance = $(window).width() / 2;
var t = "translateZ(" + centerDistance + "px)";
var style = {
  WebkitTransform: t,
  msTransform: t,
  transform: t
};
$(".slide").css(style);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!